# Sending FileList using Ajax to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send array files using JS. My code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", files);

$.ajax({
    url: './upload.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
success: function(response) {
  alert('Files uploaded successfully. ');
  console.log(response);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}

});
```

In this image you can see the response(red) from php https://beta.ctrlv.cz/mUwx and also you can see the files array data. My php code is:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['files'][0]["name"];
?>
```

I want use php script for upload, but the ajax didn't sent the array of file, which is important for uploading.

Comment: Sure its `$_POST` and not `$_FILES`?

Comment: Also, [a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2781/security/29134/uploading-files) on how to securely upload files in PHP.

Comment: When I write print_r($_FILES), the output is empty: "Array
(
)" so I don't know.. I will read it, but firstly, I need to have working upload, after I can secure it.

Comment: And where is your html form? And `formData.append("files", files);` what is `files`? where is it defined?

Comment: This is my JS script for drag and drop https://pastebin.com/968w0SiU with HTML https://pastebin.com/01P02xEv

Comment: Functions like dragEnter() or dragLeave() its not important, because this function adding only CSS style.

Comment: It all seems alright, except the part where `files` could be undefined when you're using it. Check it perhaps with console.log(files) before appending it to formdata. Secondly, it should be `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`, just verified. Also I noticed you append `<input id="staticname">` in your js code. Don't, id's should be unique in a page.

Comment: files is not empty, it can be $_FILES, but both is empty and id is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that I found:

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

So now you have a `FormData` object, ready to be sent along with the XMLHttpRequest.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/upload.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Here the source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/7282094

Hope that help.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    at uploadFiles (index.php?dir=u_tchosniper:342)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?dir=u_tchosniper:238)

Comment: Today I try to fix the code and its work, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change `contentType: false,` to `contentType: "multipart/form-data",` possibly.

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> **contentType** (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8') Type: Boolean or String When sending data to the
>   server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header. **Note**: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
>   the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
>   the browser to change the encoding. **Note**: For cross-domain requests,
>   setting the content type to anything other than
>   **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, **multipart/form-data**, or **text/plain**
>   will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
>   server.

Comment: the result is of print_r($_POST) and $_FILES is "Array ( )".